# Laravel updating eloquent event: getting the data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have been reading about eloquent events. There is an event for every interaction with a Model: creating, created, updating, updated, saving, saved, deleting, deleted, restoring, restored.

I want to know the data from a Model when it has been updated and the data it has before. Is it possible? Because the documentation havent so much info about how to use these events.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for [`getDirty()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getDirty) and [`getOriginal()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getOriginal) methods.

```
User::updating(function ($user) {
    $dirty = $user->getDirty();
    $original = $user->getOriginal();
});
```

Comment: Side note: IIRC, these are only usable on the *ing* events, not the *ed* events.