# Laravel - Monitoring Record Change

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I need an Eloquent model to represent a document uploaded to the server. One such field is the absolute path to the file. I want to be able to move the file whenever the database record is updated. I've seen that Laravel includes [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#observers) to handle such events. The problem is:

> Observers classes have method names which reflect the Eloquent events you wish to listen for. Each of these methods receives the model as their only argument.

This means that, unfortunately, with the given system I'm not able to actually move the file, since I will not have a way of retrieving both the current and new locations of the file in question. Is there another way of detecting when the value changes while having access to old and new values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you may be able to use the `updating` [model event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events) for this. You can register the event in the `boot` method of a service provider (such as `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`) or by creating an observer class as you mentioned.

The [`isDirty`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_isDirty) and `getOriginal` methods should help you check if the file needs to be moved, and then get it's original path.

For example:

```
use Storage;
use App\Document;

public function boot()
{
    Document::updating(function ($document) {
        if ($document->isDirty('file_path')) {
            // File needs to be moved
            $current_path   = $document->getOriginal('file_path');
            $new_path       = $document->file_path;

            Storage::move($current_path, $new_path);
        }
    });
}
```

See also: [Laravel updating eloquent event: getting the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984010/laravel-updating-eloquent-event-getting-the-data)